# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type News as array tried using foreach

Tags: php, arrays

Am using following code to get values for `SQL` from specific id

```
 include 'classes/connection.class.php';
                        include 'classes/news.class.php';
                        $connection = new Connection('localhost', '1video', 'sanoj', '123456');
                        $news = new News($connection->getDb());
                        $id=$_GET['name'];
                        try {
                            print_r($news->get($id));
```

and it works
RESULT

```
Array ( [id] => 103 [title] => bkjbjkuk [location] => 1video.com_81e81be69867c77aea1b9f630c4cf482.mp4 [thumb] => 1video.com_81e81be69867c77aea1b9f630c4cf482.jpg [views] => 1 [likes] => 1 [uploader] => lawrence [added_on] => 19-Feb-16 [tags] => hhuhuhuo [duration] => [comments] => [shortstory] => hihouihohoh )
```

but i need to echo result in specific location but doesn't works

Method 1

```
include 'classes/connection.class.php';
                        include 'classes/news.class.php';
                        $connection = new Connection('localhost', '1video', 'sanoj', '123456');
                        $news = new News($connection->getDb());
                        $id = $_GET['name'];
                        try {
                            print_r($news->get($id));
                            foreach ($news->result() as $row) {
                                $news= $row->title;

                            ?>
                            <h3><?php echo $vidid ?></h3>

Fatal error: Call to undefined method News::result()
```

can someone guide me how do i `echo` `array()` in various location

**class news**

```
class News {
    private $db;

    private $newsByPage = 5;

    public function  __construct(PDO $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }  
 public function get($id)
    {
        $q = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id = :id");
        $q->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if(!$q->execute())
        {
            $errors = $q->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Error while getting a news (".$errors[2].").");
        }
        else
        {
            if($res = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                return $res;
            }else{
                throw new Exception("No match for id(".$id.").");
        }}
        $q->closeCursor();
    }
}
```

Comment: how the News class looks like?

Comment: @MateiMihai function class

Comment: Please put the News class in the question..

Comment: @MateiMihai `news class` added in Question

Comment: It's unclear what are you trying to display. Your `$vidid = $row->title;` inside a `foreach` is meaningless.

Comment: You updated the post with `$news= $row->title;`, it's still meaningless. Can you please tell us with words what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like:

```
try {
    $myNews = $news->get($_GET['name']);
    echo $myNews['title'];
} // -------
```

Comment: what is `$_GET['name']`

Comment: it echo only `id` but i need to echo all values like `echo $values['title']`and `echo $values['location']`